# Vue2 Collapse - Add Class to v-collapse-wrapper when active

Tags: javascript, module, vuejs2

I am using the following module: https://roszpun.github.io/vue-collapse/#/

And I can't seem to figure out how to properly add a class to the wrapper element, as I first was thinking in doing this on onStatusChange to then bind a class, but as it's an event I'm unfamiliar to how I would add it on the element where the event came from.

I tried the following at first:

```
v-on:onStatusChange="activateClass" v-bind:class="{active:form.classActive}"
```

With then in my data just an active:false and the following method code:

```
activateClass:function(vm){
    this.form.classActive = vm.status;
},
```

While this does "add" a class to the elements, it does so ALL elements, so I can't really figure out currently how to specifically do this for one of the collapse groups.

I tried contacting the author but even though he reads my messages I am not getting a reply back in regards to my questions.

So if anyone could help me or guide me in the right direction then that would be just awesome!

Thanks in advance for further information.

Edit:

Currently doing it like following, might be a cruel attempt but this actually seems to work a bit better than redefining an element continuously.

I give the an h3 on the element the following attribute:

```
v-on:click="activateClass($event)"
```

and then use the following function to toggle the classes:

```
activateClass:function(event){
    event.target.parentElement.classList.toggle("active");
},
```

So this might be just plain JavaScript and it might not be the best solution but for this it works. If anyone has a better VueJS solution that doesn't require a lot of re-used code then by all means I'm happy to accept this change!

Edit 2:

As I've had a need for other on click events to also trigger it, I had to go back to the v-on:onStatusChange="activeClass" and just made it so it changed the actual node's class name rather than adding/toggling it on a click event.

This makes it more compatible in general with the whole module.

```
activeClass:function(e){
    if(true == e.status){
        return e.vm.nodes.toggle.className = "v-collapse-toggler active";
    }else{
        return e.vm.nodes.toggle.className = "v-collapse-toggler";
    }
},
```

Answer (score 1):

How about it?
i use ref property to selected specific collapse.

Template:

```
<div>
    <v-collapse-wrapper ref="toggleFirst" v-on:onStatusChange="activateClass('toggleFirst', 0)" v-bind:class="{active:form[0].classActive}">
      <div class="header" v-collapse-toggle>
          Click me to toggle content
      </div>
      <div class="my-content" v-collapse-content>
          This is hiddend content
      </div>
    </v-collapse-wrapper>
    <br/>
    <v-collapse-wrapper ref="toggleSecond" v-on:onStatusChange="activateClass('toggleSecond', 1)" v-bind:class="{active:form[1].classActive}">
      <div class="header" v-collapse-toggle>
          Click me to toggle content
      </div>
      <div class="my-content" v-collapse-content>
          This is hiddend content
      </div>
    </v-collapse-wrapper>
  </div>
```

Script:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueCollapse from 'vue2-collapse'

// Loading the plugin into the Vue.
Vue.use(VueCollapse)

export default {
  name: 'App',
  data () {
    return {
      form: [
        { classActive: false },
        { classActive: false }
      ]
    }
  },
  methods: {
    activateClass:function(refName, index){
      this.form[index].classActive = this.$refs[refName].status
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I was thinking something like that as well, but having to duplicate so many false or true statuses just seemed weird for me as a developer. Isn't there an easier way to do this in VueJS? than just checking the event and see what the current status is?

As the wep app itself has 10 collapse boxes (two are hidden and appear when they're needed) if I need to state classActive for all those 10 then it seems really strange and just duplicating code which as far as I know is really not the purpose of using a framework like VueJS

Either way thanks for the response I'm going to see what I can do!

Comment: Maybe you can make an init length of array so you dont need duplicate form array when add new collapse. Example: in data => i = length of collapse. mounts => this.form => loop by var i.

Comment: Ah yes I see, would this be the more right "Vue" approach as the above Edit works for me pretty good, and well I've been trying to get this to work for a couple of days now without success so I'm glad the above plain JS still works in these conditions.

Answer (score 0):

No Need to do any extra scripting to toggle content, if you want simple collapse method. Here is the example:

Template:

```
<template>
    <v-collapse-wrapper>
        <div class="header" v-collapse-toggle>
            Click me to toggle content
        </div>
        <div class="my-content" v-collapse-content>
            This is hiddend content
        </div>
    </v-collapse-wrapper>
    <br />
    <v-collapse-wrapper ref="toggleSecond">
        <div class="header" v-collapse-toggle>
            Click me to toggle content
        </div>
        <div class="my-content" v-collapse-content>
            This is hiddend content
        </div>
    </v-collapse-wrapper>
</template>
```

Scripts:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueCollapse from 'vue2-collapse'

// Loading the plugin into the Vue.
Vue.use(VueCollapse)
```

Ref: https://roszpun.github.io/vue-collapse/#/